# What does 'pivot' mean in the given context?

Tags: vocabulary

> The intention is possibly to counter the U.S. pivot towards Asia, but the Russia-China axis will have an impact elsewhere as well, including in west Asia.

What does 'pivot' mean in this context?

Comment: Vipin, have you checked a dictionary, or other source for meaning and usage? If not, [here's one](http://m-w.com). If so, what have you found, and what is confusing you?

Answer (score 2):

In American politics, 'pivot' has lately turned into a buzzword that essentially means 'change of policy focus or direction'.

In your query sentence, "the U.S. pivot towards Asia" means "the U.S.'s increased focus on  issues relating to Asia".

Comment: Aren't buzzwords confined to spelling bees?